# Flex useHandCursor in child component of parent with setCursor

Tags: apache-flex, cursor

i have the following Problem:

i have elemnts as childs of another element:

element1 --> element 1.1 ... element 1.n

In element1 i set a Custom Cursor when entering it with the mouse:

```
CursorManager.setCursor(customCursor, CursorManagerPriority.LOW, -20, -20);
```

In the element1.1 ... element 1.n components (Custom Labels) i set:

```
this.useHandCursor = true;
this.mouseChildren = false;
this.buttonMode = true;
```

The Problem: The hand cursor is not triggered when hovering over the lables. Is setCursor overwriting everything unless i remove it by using:

```
CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
```

Thanks for clarification...

Comment: Ok i just saw that the hand is a system cursor. I'm not able to use the system cursors when a cursor is set by cursor manager. But how to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the CursorManager overwrite the cursor behavior.
I would use the rollover and rollout event of a component, to switch back to handcursor or any own cursor.

BR
Frank

Comment: Yes, and using Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.HAND to set the hand and back to Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO to reset to default

Comment: But the Mouse.cursor does not overwrite setCursor by cursormanager

Comment: The main problem would be to set the parents cursor back to its value after deleting the cursor for the label and after the roll_out event for the label. So i always need to communicate the parents cursor class to the child component to set it back properly. Or i build a public method inside the parent component which i can access from everywhere.